9 Watt LED Doesn't Work in My Lamp
Our utility company sent a box of various energy conservation items.  One was a 9 Watt LED bulb.  Made by simplyconserve.  It won't work in my table lamp.  I can use a regular 60 watt bulb - no problem, but this 9 W bulb doesn't work.  Anyone know why.
The lamp was a 3 way but now only does 1 way.  Any reason the 9 Watt LED wouldn't work.  I have contacted the company via email,but no answer yet. Thanks.

Have you tried the bulb in another lamp?

One of two reasons, one it is defective, it happens, I got a CFL bulb from my power company, it lasted less than a second.  Two it is a tiny bit shorter and you need to carefully raise the centre post in the socket with the lamp unplugged/breaker turned off

You mentioned that it’s a 3-way lamp but it now only works as a one-way? Is it currently working with a 3-way bulb? If so, try it with a different 1-way bulb. The socket might have failed on the primary contact and it’s only working with the secondary contact for the 3-way bulb.

If the new bulb isn't a 3-way bulb, it'll only work as a 1-way.

Barry, great idea, I'll try.

crip659 -- oh geez, nice ... I'll just accept the non function of the 9 Watt.  Tx.

Doxylover -- Thanks, but it's the 3 way lamp and the 3 way bulb now only works as a one way.  I decided to try the 9 Watt as I'd prefer a lower light, but the 9 Watt (whatever the heck this bulb is really called) doesn't work.  Sorry for my ignorance.

Huesmann -- Sorry I was confusing.  The 3 way lamp is now only working as a one way.  The 3 way bulb only does a 1 setting.  I decided to try the 9 Watt thinking it would work as a less bright alternative, but it doesn't work at all.  Thanks.
